# Does Pi change when gravity changes

Tags: gravity

Will Pi have the same value on the surface of say Jupiter, compared to the value of PI on Earth. Or does Pi vary with gravity?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns a mathematical constant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\pi$ is just a number. It doesn't vary with *anything*.

The ratio of the circumference to the diameter of a circle varies with geometry, so in the general case, this definition doesn't hold. But there are other definitions, such as
$$
\pi = \int_{-1}^{1}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}},
$$
or
$$
\mathrm{The\,smallest\,positive\,number} \, x \, \mathrm{for\,which}\, \arccos(2x) = 0.
$$
The latter definition can also be expressed a power series, which is independent of geometry.